# Excel cells not updated from formula from another sheet and displays 0 instead values until you not press that cell

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have excel, that is created by the Apache POI api.
Some cells have formula that pick up data from another sheet from this excel file:

[image]

But it's not updated with real values:

[image]

until I choose cell (D2) and click on formula field at the top:
I need that all values be updated at the moment I download this file from the system.

How to fix it? Appreciate any help.

Updates:
I added two lines of code from example ( poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation ) by @Axel Richter

[image]

and now it failed while excel creation:

[image]

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation

Comment: who is blaming with -1 and why?

Comment: @AxelRichter, thanks a lot! You saved my hours :)
wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true); // is the solution!

Comment: To your `FormulaParseException`: In `apache poi` setting a formula in a cell is `cell.setCellFormula("'Sheet2'!A2")`; without the leading equals sign.